# Python - Get newest dict value where string = string

Tags: python, dictionary, max

I have this code and it works. But I want to get two different files.

`file_type` returns either `NP` or `KL`. So I want to get the NP file with the max value and I want to get the KL file with the max value.

The dict looks like

```
{"Blah_Blah_NP_2022-11-01_003006.xlsx": "2022-03-11",
"Blah_Blah_KL_2022-11-01_003006.xlsx": "2022-03-11"}
```

This is my code and right now I am just getting the max date without regard to time. Since the date is formatted how it is and I don't care about time, I can just use `max()`.

I'm having trouble expanding the below code to give me the greatest NP file and the greatest KL file. Again, `file_type` returns the NP or KL string from the file name.

```
file_dict = {}
file_path = Path(r'\\place\Report')
for file in file_path.iterdir():
    if file.is_file():
        path_object = Path(file)
        filename = path_object.name
        stem = path_object.stem
        file_type = file_date = stem.split("_")[2]
        file_date = stem.split("_")[3]
        file_dict.update({filename: file_date})
        newest = max(file_dict, key=file_dict.get)
return newest
```

I basically want `newest` where `file_type` = `NP` and also `newest` where `file_type` = `KL`

Comment: Does the `003006` part have no meaning to you? (i.e. it's not a time or something?)

Answer (score 1):

You could filter the dictionary into two dictionaries (or however many you need if there's more types) and then get the max date for any of those.

But the whole operation can be done efficiently in only few lines:

```
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import datetime


def get_newest():
    maxs = {}
    for file in Path(r'./examples').iterdir():
        if file.is_file():
            *_, t, d, _ = file.stem.split('_')
            d = datetime(*map(int, d.split('-')))
            maxs[t] = d if t not in maxs else max(d, maxs[t])
    return maxs


print(get_newest())
```

This:

- collects the maximum date for each type into a `dict` `maxs`
- loops over the files like you did (but in a location where I created some examples following your pattern)
- only looks at the files, like your code
- assumes the files all meet your pattern, and splits them over `'_'`, only keeping the next to last part as the date and the part before it as the type
- converts the date into a `datetime` object
- keeps whichever is greater, the new date or a previously stored one (if any)

Result:

```
{'KL': datetime.datetime(2023, 11, 1, 0, 0), 'NP': datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 2, 0, 0)}
```

The files in the folder:

```
Blah_Blah_KL_2022-11-01_003006.txt
Blah_Blah_KL_2023-11-01_003006.txt
Blah_Blah_NP_2022-11-02_003051.txt
Blah_Blah_NP_2022-11-01_003006.txt
Blah_Blah_KL_2021-11-01_003006.txt
```

In the comments you asked

> no idea how the above code it getting the diff file types and the max. Is it just looing for all the diff types in general? It's hard to know what each piece is with names like s, d, t, etc. Really lost on *_, t, d, _ = and also d = datetime(*map(int, d.split('-')))

That's a fair point, I prefer short names when I think the meaning is clear, but a descriptive name might have been better. `t` is for `type` (and `type` would be a bad name, shadowing `type`, so perhaps `file_type`). `d` is for `date`, or `dt` for datetime might have been better. I don't see `s`?

The `*_, t, d, _ =`  is called '[extended tuple unpacking](https://peps.python.org/pep-3132/)', it takes all the results from what follows and only keeps the 3rd and 2nd to last, as `t` and `d` respectively, and throws the rest away. The `_` takes up a position, but the underscore indicates we "don't care" about whatever is in that position. And the `*_` similarly gobbles up all values at the start, as explained in the linked PEP article.

The `d = datetime(*map(int, d.split('-')))` is best read from the inside out. `d.split('-')` just takes a date string like `'2022-11-01'` and splits it. The `map(int, ...)` that's applied to the result applies the `int()` function to every part of that result - so it turns `('2022', '11', '01')` into `(2022, 11, 1)`. The `*` in front of `map()` spreads the results as parameters to `datetime` - so, `datetime(2022, 11, 1)` would be called in this example.

This is what I both like and hate about Python - as you get better at it, there are very concise (and arguably beautiful - user @ArtemErmakov seems to agree) ways to write clean solutions. But they become hard to read unless you know most of the basics of the language. They're not easy to understand for a beginner, which is arguably a bad feature of a language.

To answer the broader question: since the loop takes each file, gets the type (like 'KL') from it and gets the date, it can then check the dictionary, add the date if the type is new, or if the type was already in the dictionary, update it with the maximum of the two, which is what this line does:

```
maxs[t] = d if t not in maxs else max(d, maxs[t])
```

I would recommend you keep asking questions - and whenever you see something like this code, try to break it down into all it small parts, and see what specific parts you don't understand. Python is a powerful language.

As a bonus, here is the same solution, but written a bit more clearly to show what is going on:

```
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import datetime


def get_newest_too():
    maximums = {}
    for file_path in Path(r'./examples').iterdir():
        if file_path.is_file():
            split_file = file_path.stem.split('_')
            file_type = split_file[-3]
            date_time_text = split_file[-2]
            date_time_parts = (int(part) for part in date_time_text.split('-'))
            date_time = datetime(*date_time_parts)  # spreading is just right here
            if file_type in maximums:
                maximums[file_type] = max(date_time, maximums[file_type])
            else:
                maximums[file_type] = date_time
    return maximums


print(get_newest_too())
```

Edit: From the comments, it became clear that you had trouble selecting the actual file of each specific type for which the date was the maximum for that type.

Here's how to do that:

```
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import datetime


def get_newest():
    maxs = {}
    for file in Path(r'./examples').iterdir():
        if file.is_file():
            *_, t, d, _ = file.stem.split('_')
            d = datetime(*map(int, d.split('-')))
            maxs[t] = (d, file) if t not in maxs else max((d, file), maxs[t])
    return {f: d for _, (d, f) in maxs.items()}


print(get_newest())
```

Result:

```
{WindowsPath('examples/Blah_Blah_KL_2023-11-01_003006.txt'): datetime.datetime(2023, 11, 1, 0, 0), WindowsPath('examples/Blah_Blah_NP_2022-11-02_003051.txt'): datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 2, 0, 0)}
```

Comment: So it works and I modified it to put the file.name in the dict instead of the date. But I have absolutely no idea how the above code it getting the diff file types and the max. Is it just looing for all the diff types in general? It's hard to know what each piece is with names like s, d, t, etc. Really lost on `*_, t, d, _ =` and also `d = datetime(*map(int, d.split('-')))`

Comment: That's fair, @UneRoue - I've added some explanation and hope that helps. Feel free to ask more if there's still something unclear.

Comment: Thanks. So what in the unpacking tells it to work backwards in order to get the values I care about. And how is the dict being put together? Those are last two things I don't understand. How would I reverse the key and value of the dict to be in reverse order? Thanks again.

Comment: In unpacking, Python tries to match the number of elements on the right and assign them to the left. So, `a, b, c = 1, 2, 3` works. But if you include a `*`, that element on the left will receive all the leftovers, so `*a, b = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5` assigns `5` to `b` and everything else to `a` (as a list). The dict is constructed by `m = {}`, after that, you can just assign key/value pairs as `m[key] = value`. Reversing that wouldn't make sense while finding the max - after all, you want the max for each type, not the type for each max. Reversing it later would only work if all the dates differ.

Comment: Since the loop deals with one file at a time, the type will be fixed. It's either `'KL'` or `'NP'` or whatever. And you'll be updating the max for *that* type, the only two options are: 1.) it's not there yet, in which case you assign it, 2.) it's there already, in which you replace it with the max of the old value and the new value. And that's what that statement does: assign to `maxs[t]`, assign `d` if `t` wasn't in `maxs` yet, otherwise assign `max(d, maxs[t])`, where `maxs[t]` is whatever the value is as `max()` gets called.

Comment: I understand m = {} is the start of the dict. I meant how was it being constructed in maxs[t] = d if t not in maxs else max(d, maxs[t]). As in, what specifically is happening in that line. If you wanted to use a key other than type - you may need to reverse. Finding the max and the result you provide in the end are two different things. That' why I had it laid out in op how I did. Finding the max wasn't the end goal. Finding the max, and then putting the dat into a dict with data I cared about was,

Comment: "Finding the max and the result you get in the end are two different things." - I don't think so, but perhaps I don't understand your point. The result `{'KL': datetime.datetime(2023, 11, 1, 0, 0), 'NP': datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 2, 0, 0)}` is a dictionary of the maximums for all types encountered. And whatever type is encountered in a filename, needs to be used to either assign it as a new value, or the max of the existing value and the most recent one.

Comment: Finding the max and the result you provide in the end are two different things. Finding the max for types was step one. Once you have those file names, the type doesn't matter and the ending dict doesn't need the key to be the type, but rather something else needed for the next bit of work..

Comment: Ah, I see - you say you want the name for the file of a specific type with the max date, not just the type itself; I'll add a brief update to the answer.

Comment: I barely see what is happening here - `return {f: d for _, (d, f) in maxs.items()}`. It looks like you're taking d and file from maxs and returning them in a dict like `f: d`. (I assume f is supposed to be file. It's hard to ell with the name being different.) I don't see how you're getting the entire windows file path when it doesn't exist in the result. Where is the windows file path coming from in `return {f: d for _, (d, f) in maxs.items()}`. How was it stored in maxs[t] and how was it pulled into it in the first place? The biggest question is what is `f: d for _` doing?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think explaining everything about dictionary comprehensions here is going well beyond the scope of the question. The solution works, does exactly what you said you needed, and is using fairly basic Python constructs, with an already inordinate amount of explanation provided. The code is right there - you should be able to read it with minimal help from Python documentation. If you have a specific question about why or how it works, perhaps consider posting a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You could construct another `dict` containing only the items you need:

`file_dict_NP = {key:value for key, value in file_dict.items() if 'NP' in key}`

And then do the same thing on it:

`newest_NP = max(file_dict_NP, key=file_dict_NP.get)`

Comment: Did you mean file_dict_NP on the last snippet after key=? I get `ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence`

Comment: I did. Corrected.